# Oracle package is no longer working via xdb

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, wsdl

After a migration from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.4 I'm unable to retreive data from the package. 
In the wsdl definition I noticed a difference between the old and the new enviroment:

```
New environment: <xsd:element name="GETSTREETInput"> 
Old environment: <xsd:element name="COUTPUT_STREET-GETSTREETInput">
```

and `OUTPUT_STREET` is a datatype. But tt's not appended anymore in the wsdl.

When I create a soap call manually that uses `COUTPUT_STREET-GETSTREETInput` I can retrieve data from the new environment.

Does anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem(oracle bug):
Solved in patch: 16199543

Function Element Name is Different than the One Described in the Documentation Guide in Wsdl, in 11.2.0.4 and 11.2.0.3 + Patch 14780408 ( Doc ID 1613809.1 )